# How can I display a URL Preview from a Text Input in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, photo

Is it possible to build a function in React that generates a preview of a website once the URL of the website is typed into an input field?

My approach would be:

- Set a URLPreview state of the component to ""
- Have users type URL into the input field, and update the state upon submitting the inputted value
- Then, build a preview space (div, Card, etc) to generate a preview of the website

I just don't know how to tell my app to generate a preview of another website, like google for example.

I also don't want to have to deal with COORS--

is this doable? If so, can someone help me build my function? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to create an actual thumbnail image of the site or create some sort of snippet card based off of the target site's metadata? Either way, you'll most likely need a supporting backend that you create yourself or a third-party service like https://www.linkpreview.net.